# How to remove UINavigationbar prompt programmatically? 

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have a view controller, and I set the navigation bar with prompt in IB. But I want to remove the prompt and make the bar as "1 line" sometimes. how can I do it in code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
[[self navigationItem] setPrompt: nil];
```

This animates the removal of the prompt.