# Remove UINavigationBar prompt when push back button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have an issue with the prompt of an UINavitgationBar.

I have a view with a UINavigationBar, but without prompt. When I go forward to the next view, I set the prompt properly in the UINavigationBar, but when I push the back button and I go back to the last view, the prompt disappears (nice), but the frame for the prompt is still in the view as a black frame.

Here I show you what happens:

[image]

As you can see, the space for the prompt is still in the view, and I would like to collapse the UINavigationBar as in the first view.

I have tried this, but it does not work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7049718/1721595

Thanks!!

Comment: try to remove promt effect in viewWillAppear method of the view where you don't want it..

Comment: I have tried that also, didn't work...

Comment: @kemmitorz have you got any solution for this??

Comment: @jigs sorry but I didn't find anything. At the end I had to delete the prompt because I didn't have enough time to spend in UI issues. Sorry! =(